# Python: library is installed through command line but not available in Spyder IDE?

Tags: python

The library in particular I am trying to use is PyTrends.

I go to install it using command-line and use: `pip3 install pytrends`. It installs.

Then I type: `pip3 list`, it's in the list, installed.

Then I open up Spyder, I write the following:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
```

In the Spyder console window it says `No module named 'pytrends'`
When I type: `help('pytrends')`, it says the same.

What could possibly be causing this issue where the command-list shows the library is installed but when I go to use it in Spyder it says its not there.

Additionally, I typed: `pip3 list` in the IPython console and still shows it's not there.

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Check which `pip3` your console is using.  On Windows: `where pip3`, on Linux `which pip3`.  It may be using pip from a different environment.

Comment: When I use ```where pip3``` it generates: ```C:\Users\Preston_Jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip3.exe```

Comment: In python, what is the output of `import sys; print(sys.executable)`?

Comment: ```runfile('C:/Users/Preston_Jarvis/Desktop/G_Trender.py', wdir='C:/Users/Preston_Jarvis/Desktop')
C:\Program Files\Spyder\Python\python.exe```

Comment: @James what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, your Spyder installation is running in a different environment than pip.

Your pip environment uses: `C:\Users\Preston_Jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe`, but your instance of Spyder uses: `C:\Program Files\Spyder\Python\python.exe`.

You can change the path to the Python interpreter that Spyder uses by:

- Tools > Preferences [Open Preferences pane]
- Python Interpreter (side tab) > Python Interpreter (sub window)
- select the radio button "Use the following Python interpreter"
- enter the path to the interpreter used by pip: `C:\Users\Preston_Jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe`

Comment: Works 100% Absolutely perfect answer! Thank you so very much!

Comment: A new issue has presented itself. When I go to run ```from pytrends.requests import TredReq``` the IPython console window presents a box that reads: ```Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.0.1 and < 2.1.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.

You can install it by running in a system terminal:

conda install spyder‑kernels=2.0

or

pip install spyder‑kernels==2.0.*```